# Looking for a parts list application

Tags: applications

I am looking for an application like a shopping list, that will let me put in items with the prices and give me a final total...so that if I have a project, I can put in all the prices(scanning barcodes would be a plus) of items in the project while i am out and about.

I have tried a couple different searches, but havent gotten any really good hits on it.

Comment: Wow that is a great idea for an app. Any Android devs out there? Either way I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ShoppingCalc](http://www.appbrain.com/app/shoppingcalc/com.xllusion.shopping) does this pretty simply if you're willing to live without the barcode scanning (I like the zero-clutter interface).

Comment: It works for me for now, i guess ill have to write something for this myself... thanks

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search returned [ToMarket](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-oliassolutions-tomarketfull-xqA.aspx) . It looks like its original purpose and design is for Groceries but you can use it for any type of item. The description says it supports bar codes and lets you put items with prices and quantity in the cart and gives you a final total. Sounds like exactly what your looking for based on the question. It looks like a nice app, I'm downloading it now for myself.

EDIT: This app is actually pretty cool, it has some default items when you first open it but if you go over to the "need" tab it is blank. When you add an item it gives quite a few details you can add to it, including whether or not it is taxable. I also noticed there is a feature to export your lists or to share it with others via SMS or email.

Answer (score 1):

I've suggested Springpad ([their website](http://springpadit.com/) and [on appbrain](http://www.appbrain.com/app/springpad/com.springpad)) as a [good note-taking app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/305/what-do-you-use-for-note-taking/306#306) but it would serve this purpose well too. Especially since it has a scanning feature and web-sync.